# Parsec - Input delimited by subset of main content

Tags: haskell, irc, parsec

As a sort of practice project, I want to implement a library that parses IRC messages. One of the things I'll have to parse are shortnames, given by the BNF:

`shortname  =  ( letter / digit ) *( letter / digit / "-" ) *( letter / digit )`

I have the parsers `alphaNum` and `(alphaNum <|> char '-')`, corresponding to those elements, that's easy. However, I have trouble combining them to conform to the specification. `between alphaNum alphaNum (alphaNum <|> char '-')` doesn't work, and I have trouble incorporating `lookAhead` in a way that makes it do what I want it to.

Comment: Since `( letter / digit )` is a subset of `( letter / digit / "-" )`, it seems to me that the definition is equivalent to `shortname = ( letter / digit ) *( letter / digit / "-" )`. Are you sure the definition of `shortname` is as you intended?

Comment: The point is to disallow leading and trailing dashes, which is absent in your collapsed version.

Comment: Then your definition should be `shortname = ( letter / digit ) *( letter / digit / "-" ) +( letter / digit )` (or without `*`/`+` at all).

Comment: Actually, you are right. That's curious - I copied the definition straight out of RFC 2812, which defines the IRC protocol.
Which means my interpretation of the authors intent was wrong, I suppose.

Comment: Looks like indeed there is a mistake in the RFC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the final part (a letter or a number, but not a dash) is consumed by the previous part. I'd suggest changing the grammar to

> shortname = ( letter / digit ) *( *( "-" ) ( letter / digit ) )

or perhaps more efficient

> shortname = +( letter / digit ) *( +( "-" ) +( letter / digit ) )

This ensures that while the inner part can contain both letters, digits and dashes, any dash must always be followed by a letter/digit. A parsec solution could be

```
shortName :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m String
shortName = (++) <$> many1 alphaNum
                 <*> (concat <$> many ((++) <$> many1 (char '-')
                                            <*> many1 alphaNum))
```